# python regex to remove all text not between '<' and '>'

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want the following string

```
Doe, John PGM GUY FOOBARINC MD (USA) <john.doe@email.mail>
```

to become

```
john.doe@email.mail
```

while using the `series.str.replace()` function

I have code like the following

```py
email= email.squeeze()
if '<' in email[0] and '>' in email[0]: # Checking to see if strings in this series are formatted with <>'s. Not all are, hence the check

email.str.replace(r"[^<]*\<|\>[^>]*", "")
```

which seems to work [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5E%3C%5D*%5C%3C%7C%5C%3E%5B%5E%3E%5D*&test_string=Doe%2C%20John%20PGM%20GUY%20FOOBARINC%20MD%20(USA)%20%3Cjohn.doe%40email.mail%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), but doesn't work when I run the code. I simply get back the same strings, no edits made to them at all.

Comment: Instead of removing everything outside, use `.str.extract()` to get what's inside.

Comment: Maybe something like this [`^.*?<|>[^<>]*?$|>[^<>]*?<`](https://regex101.com/r/t6wMA2/1) could help to start your process. But you'd better clarify what should happen in edge cases

Comment: `email.partition('<')[2].rstrip('>')`

Answer (score 2):

Extract it instead:

```
<([^<>]+)>
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/HnTurC/1).

Answer (score 1):

2 prior remarks

- The given input is presented as a string, yet the required tool [.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is from the pandas module and takes pandas series (and will return a dataframe)
- direct extraction of the content may be more convenient than replacing the rest, left and right, with empty strings. The regex becomes very simple.

Inserting the string as a series, and using *.str.extract* instead of *.str.replace*, returns the requested output:

```
e = pd.Series(email).str.extract('<(.+)>')
e
                     0
0  john.doe@email.mail
```

Extracting the email string from the dataframe:

```
e.loc[0,0]
'john.doe@email.mail'
```

A most basic regex , which works this way:

- Use '<' and '>' as fence for the capture
- Group capture: return only the content between '(' brackets ')'

Not going into email regex validation here.